# Transaction not received, showing on Polygonscan but not Etherscan

Tags: etherscan

This transaction is in status "Success" [in Polygon scan](https://polygonscan.com/tx/0xd4e46c6d879bbda255402227497bd928406a7e5ed2be0d7e34ebfa0b8abe46a8). [In Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xd4e46c6d879bbda255402227497bd928406a7e5ed2be0d7e34ebfa0b8abe46a8), it's not listed. It also hasn't been received in my wallet. It's been 24 hours. How does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: Fix what?! Polygonscan shows transactions in Polygon network and Etherscan shows transactions in Ethereum network! These are two different networks!

Comment: That answers the question, thank you.